# How to import TDMS file into MATLAB environment？

Tags: matlab

[Here's the link](http://www.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28771-converttdms-v9) of the program.

[Here's the link](http://vdisk.weibo.com/s/hBvz5) of the original waveform.

[Here's the link](http://vdisk.weibo.com/s/hBvyA) of the imported waveform.

[Here's the](http://vdisk.weibo.com/s/hBvyP) ratio.

The strange thing is that the imported waveform looks same as the original waveform,I have expected to get a scalar ratio when use the original data ./ the imported data, but surprisingly the ratio points are so scattered.
Is there anyone can tell me why? Or recommend to me a program to import TDMS file.

Comment: Tried one of your links but it will just show a loading page and then nothing happens.

Comment: I have changed the links, please try again!